# Trying to use substr to get part of string with index but wrong output is coming

Tags: php, string

I am trying to use substr to get part of string with index

```
<?php
echo substr("2019-10-10T02:10:30.413291+05:30",11,16); 
?>
```

but the output is 02:10:30.413291+

what is know the output should have been 02:10

I can't get what am I doing wrong please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). The third parameter is `length` - how many chars you want to "select" past `start`.

> If length is given and is positive, the string returned will contain at most length characters beginning from start (depending on the length of string).

```
echo substr("2019-10-10T02:10:30.413291+05:30", 11, 5);
```

This outputs `02:10`.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is the **length** of the substring you wish to grab (not the index of the end of the substring):

> If length is given and is positive, the string returned will contain at most length characters beginning from start (depending on the length of string).

In order to grab your desired substring of `2:10`, you're looking for a length of `5`:

```
echo substr("2019-10-10T02:10:30.413291+05:30",11,5); // 2:10
```

This can be seen working [here](https://3v4l.org/L2XYa).